# Getting 'you do not have permission to view this directory or page' on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, mobile, azure-web-app-service

I've had a website running on Azure now for a while, and I've not had any problems until today when I discovered that browsing to it via a mobile device (tested on Android (Chrome/Firefox) and Apple (iPhone 6 - Safari) ) I get a:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page

error. I've not changed anything on the site, the last publish was 5 days ago, and it was working then. Both my staging *and* prod environments have gone down like this.

It looks like it's returning a 403, but I can't see why.

The site is an ASP.NET MVC5 site, running as an Azure Web App.

**Update**

OK, I've now run up a test version of the site with the `[RequireHttps]` attribute removed from the controllers - now I can navigate to the pages by just `http`, but `https` gives me the permission error.

Comment: I would recommend you use [fiddler](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler) to capture your mobile device network traces, then you could compare it with the request from the browser on your PC to narrow this issue.

Comment: Thanks for that - I've given it a whirl - using fiddler as a proxy annoyingly it works - when I check what the phone is sending vs what the pc is sending - the user-agent is the only difference - if I swap my user agent on the pc to the same as the phone - there is no problem on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem, in my `web.config` I had a URL rewrite to prevent SSL3.0 access (based on this post: [Disabling SSL3 in in Azure websites](https://www.troyhunt.com/disabling-ssl-3-in-azure-websites-and/)).

After switching on the logs in Azure and loading the pages up I saw the 403 error with the message

> SSLv3 connections are forbidden by this site

in it. This came from the url rewrite.

My PC was happy loading as I have BitDefender and that was injecting it's own SSL cert into place over the one supplied by my site. Turning off SSL Scanning in BitDefender gave me the error on all browsers.

So the solution so far is to remove the SSL3 rewrite and look into another way to achieve the same thing.